# Error running Scala Bulkcopy on Azure Databricks Runtime 7.3 LTS

Tags: scala, databricks, azure-databricks

We have recently upgraded our Azure Databricks runtime from 6.4 to 7.3LTS. And the issue is that my Scala bulk insert for SQL Server MI is not working anymore.
The error i am getting is as below

```
%scala
val bulkCopyConfig = Config(Map(
"url" -> jdbchostURL,
"databaseName" -> jdbcDatabase,
"user" -> jdbcUsername,
"password" -> jdbcPassword,
"dbTable" -> jdbcTableName,
"bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "200000",
"bulkCopyTableLock" -> "true",
"bulkCopyTimeout" -> "600"
))
```

The error that i am getting is

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class

I have checked GitHub and other sites, no specific answer to the problem is available.
Please help

Tried multiple solutions but to no avail, expecting a solution that can fix the above error and enable to run scala 2.11 code on scala 2.12 easily.

Answer (score 0):

this kind of error is usually caused by incompatible connector - make sure that your SQL Server connector is compiled for Scala 2.12 (`com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.1.0` for 7.3/Spark 3.0 - see [compatibility table on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector/)) - it's impossible to use connector compiled for Scala 2.11 on DBR 7.3.

P.S. It makes sense to go to DBR 10.4 already, as 7.3 will be end of life in ~half year

Comment: I have upgraded to spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.1.0. But now i am getting below error in my scala code: object sqldb is not a member of package com.microsoft. not sure how do i import the new library in scala. The current library import is as : import com.microsoft.sqldb.spark.config.Config. what needs to be changed here ??